# Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of substring function error for date data type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to execute the below code but yet its throwing me the error for this type of combination.

colud anyone let me know why this error occurs ?

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @TimeDimensionDate AS DATE

SET @TimeDimensionDate = '1998-01-01'
Select CONVERT ( DATE,REPLACE (@TimeDimensionDate,SUBSTRING (@TimeDimensionDate,6,2),'01')) 

END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `replace()` on a date.  That means that the date is being converted to a string, using the local settings.  One method would be to explicitly convert the date to a string using a format such as 121.

Alternatively:

```
select dateadd(month, 1 - month(@TimeDimensionDate), @TimeDimensionDate)
```